# How the array is interpreted in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array [1,2], I tried :

```
$("#test").append([1,2]);
```

**Output :**

> 12

And when I try :

```
 $("#test").append("<br>"+[1,2]);
```

**Output :**

> 1,2

And when I use `alert` :

```
alert([1,2])`
```

**Output :**

> 1,2

So can someone explain how the array is interpreted when we output it in jquery  ?

Comment: Array is converted to string using `toString()` and that string is appended.

Comment: What you call JSON is not JSON.

Comment: jQuery converts array into jQuery object. Allways. You can even write `$([1,2,3]).each(fn)`

Comment: While append anything to DOM element, javascript initially convert that into string (toString). While we append number array [1,2] it convert each number in array(1,2) toString so it returns 1 and 2 and it will append with DOM. While converting JSON object to string it generally return [Object,object] so it appending this into DOM. This is general behavior of Javascript

Comment: @Tushar tostring method convert an array [1,2] into string 1,2 So it should append 1,2 But it is appending 12 But when i use `.append("<br>"+[1,2]) `then it appends `1,2` . I expalin it in my question as well – beginner

Comment: Because, `append` also expects an array of DOM elements/Text Elements. When array is passed, those are considered as text elements and are added. When concatenating with string, `toString()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we append only  array. it outputs its all values without commas(,)

```
$("#test").append(["he","ll","o"]);
```

output will be

```
hello
```

when we use any string after (or before) the  array , even empty string (i.e double quotes "" ). the array is also considered as string and converted into string using `toString()` method and gives output with commas(,)

```
$("#test").append(["he","ll,"o"] +"<br>");
```

or

```
$("#test").append(["he","ll,"o"]+ ""); //even if empty string added
```

in both cases   array  will interpreted as string  Both will give output with commas

```
he,ll,o
```

In the case

```
 $("#test").append("<br>" + [1,2]);
```

array also considered as string  and output will be with commas(,)

```
1,2
```

In other  case

```
$("#test").append([1,2]);
```

array outputs its all valus without comma, so output will be

```
12
```

And in the case of `alert([1,2])` array is always converted into string using `toString()`  thats why it outputs

```
 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

As **@Tushar** mentioned in **[the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017223/how-the-array-is-interpreted-in-jquery#comments-40017223)** you've just to convert your array to string using **[`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString)** then append it, as example below show.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#test").append([1,2].toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test">Result here : </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* jQuery behavior, it's JavaScript itself. When you try to pass an array as argument to JS functions that produce **output** to the window or DOM, it gets converted to a **string** separated by commas (using [`toString()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp)).

Example:

```
document.write([1, 2, 3]); // outputs 1,2,3
```

which outputs the same as:

```
document.write("1,2,3"); // also outputs 1,2,3
```